# Application context: modify return point of main()

Tags: c, linux

Suppose I'm developing a library in plain C. The library requires the user to call `lib_init()` on the begin of their programs to make it work. `lib_init()` will alloc some memory space for it's own use (ctrl variables, a a list, a fifo, etc).

Now the question: Is there any way to free this content after the program finishes without forcing the user to call some cleanup-function like `lib_clean()` or `lib_finish()`?

The library to be developed is a threads-manipulating library, something like a cheap version of POSIX threads. I was wondering if there was any way to modify the return point of main (to jump to a cleanup function) before it ends by doing some clever context manipulation with `swapcontext()`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you willing to do horrible, dangerous hacks to achieve something useless? There is no need at all to free these resources when the program terminates. When a process dies, all of its resources go with it. The only time you would need to take any explicit action is if the resources you created are not process-local, for example temporary files in the filesystem or POSIX or SYSV shared memory, semaphores, message queues, etc. However, you really should design your applications to be tolerant to such resources being left around, since the user/administrator could always forcibly kill your process with `SIGKILL`, in which case you would have no way to clean up.

If you really want to, or need to, clean up resources on exit, the `atexit` function provides you the correct way to do this. However, you should take care to make sure you don't register it more than once, or you could make things much worse and invoke undefined behavior by freeing already-freed resources. Note that avoiding double-initialization and double-registration of your `atexit` functions requires proper synchronization in case the calling program is multi-threaded and calls the init function from multiple places. You should use either `pthread_once` or the equivalent logic with mutexes to ensure that initialization, including `atexit` registration, only happens once.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! The reason is I was unsure whether the resources were automatically freed when the process is finished or not, and also just willing to sneak into the system to check how it works :) anyways, the atexit function should work for the basic functionality I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `atexit()` should be able to do what you want. It registers a "callback" function that will be called when the application exits (either from returning from `main` or when `exit()` is called). It does not get run if the application CRASHES (or the user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the program, etc), you will have to implement signal handlers to solve that (and that's trickier, since there can only be one signal handler for a given signal).